# Nullpointer when adding code to textblock

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro

I'm trying to insert the time into the textblock but for some reason it says its null when its not? Did i miss out any code?

```
DateTime localtime = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime universal = localtime.ToUniversalTime();
        txtm12.Text = universal.ToString();
```

Comment: txtm12 could certainly be null, we have no way to tell from your code snippet.  If you're getting a null reference exception, it is undoubtably null.

Comment: when are you calling this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check to make sure that your txtm12 (textbox i assume) is properly initialized. If it hasnt been then it will throw a null reference exception.

Comment: Do you have it declared in the control's XAML?

Comment: I'm guessing you're attempting to use it before it's constructed and initialized by the WinRT runtime.  Try moving the code to execute _after_ the `InitializeComponent()` method runs.  See M Patel's answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the code you supplied and it seems to be returning a result fine. It would appear that your control is null when you try to assign a value to it. Make sure you control has not been disposed elsewhere and if it is fully rendered before you assign values to it.

```
DateTime localtime = DateTime.Now;
DateTime universal = localtime.ToUniversalTime();

if(txtm12 == null)
    Console.WriteLine("Textbox not yet initialised");
else
    txtm12.Text = universal.ToString();
```

Another point to think about is where you are assigning the value to the control. If it is in the constructor, remove it and place in the form load method instead.